# Double grouping ?? is it possible?

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I am trying to modify my reports mysql query, the current query is :

```
select `companies`.`companynameturkish` AS `Company_Name`, (round(count(`applications`.`company_id`) / (select count(*) from applications where ((`applications`.`appstatus` = '3') ))*100)) AS `Work Load`,
sum(`applications`.`netprice`) AS `Total Cost`,`companies`.`percentage` AS `Firm %`
, round(((sum(`applications`.`netprice`) * 49) / 100),2) AS `Comission`
, round(((sum(`applications`.`netprice`) * `companies`.`percentage`) / 100),2) AS `Benefits`
, round(((sum(`applications`.`netprice`) * 49) / 100),2) - round(((sum(`applications`.`netprice`) * `companies`.`percentage`) / 100),2) AS `Diff`
, count(`applications`.`company_id`) AS `Quantity`
from (`applications` left join `companies` on((`applications`.`company_id` = `companies`.`id`)))
where ((`applications`.`appstatus` = '3') and (`applications`.`recordcreationdate`
like concat(curdate(),'%'))) group by `applications`.`company_id` order by `Work Load` desc
```

And here is the explain :

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   PRIMARY applications    NULL    ALL company_id  NULL    NULL    NULL    6   16.67   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY companies   NULL    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   db.applications.company_id  1   100.00  Using where
2   SUBQUERY    applications    NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    6   16.67   Using where
```

What I am trying to do is to add new column and group by it, that column is : provider type (applications.type), so applications grouped by applications.type left join tbl_provider on applications.type = tbl_provider.id, selecting tbl_provider.provider_name for this column , these are my tables structure to help you know what I am talking about :

```
CREATE TABLE `applications` (
  `serial` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `policy_no` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_id` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `dataentry` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `creator_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `approved_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `provider_percentage` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `fathername` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `passportno` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_main` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_sub` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `length` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `paid_price` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `netprice` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `saved_price` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `confirmed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `appstatus` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `startdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `enddate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `recordcreationdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `recordlastediteddate` datetime DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `cancel_reason` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `image_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `net_price_deduced` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status_change_1_to_3` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`serial`),
  KEY `company_id` (`company_id`),
  KEY `policy_no` (`policy_no`),
  KEY `type` (`type`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `policy_no_ft` (`policy_no`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `companies` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `manager_id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `companynamearabic` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `companynameturkish` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `managername` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `companyspeciality` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `percentage` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `companytelephone` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `companyemail` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `contactname` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `contactphone` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `website` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `balancetype` tinyint(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `companylimit` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `balance` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `recordcreationdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `recordlastediteddate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `auto_approve` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `avl2mrkz` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `tbl_provider` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `provider_name` varchar(225) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `no_of_slabs` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `age_from` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `age_to` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `provider_percentage` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `provider_income` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Thank you very much !

Comment: You're more likely to get a response if you cut down your question to the core of what you need to know. Is this a minimal example demonstrating your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is tie in `tbl_provider` to the existing query, via a `LEFT JOIN` on `applications.type = tbl_provider.id`, and adding `provider_name` from `tbl_provider` to the `SELECT` list, and to the `GROUP BY` clause.

NOTE: With a `LEFT JOIN`, if there's no matching provider, `provider_name` will be `NULL`. It should still appear in the `SELECT` list, and can still be grouped on, but it seemed worth noting.

Basically, to group on multiple columns, you just need to list all the columns after `GROUP BY`.

I believe this will do what you're looking for, if the above is correct (query reformatted slightly for readability):

```
select `companies`.`companynameturkish` AS `Company_Name`
      ,`tbl_provider`.`provider_name`
      ,(round(count(`applications`.`company_id`) / (select count(*) from applications where ((`applications`.`appstatus` = '3') ))*100)) AS `Work Load`
      ,sum(`applications`.`netprice`) AS `Total Cost`
      ,`companies`.`percentage` AS `Firm %`
      ,round(((sum(`applications`.`netprice`) * 49) / 100),2) AS `Comission`
      ,round(((sum(`applications`.`netprice`) * `companies`.`percentage`) / 100),2) AS `Benefits`
      ,round(((sum(`applications`.`netprice`) * 49) / 100),2) - round(((sum(`applications`.`netprice`) * `companies`.`percentage`) / 100),2) AS `Diff`
      ,count(`applications`.`company_id`) AS `Quantity`
  from ((`applications` left join `companies` on (`applications`.`company_id` = `companies`.`id`))
                        left join `tbl_provider` on (`applications`.`type` = `tbl_provider`.`id`))
 where (    (`applications`.`appstatus` = '3')
        and (`applications`.`recordcreationdate` like concat(curdate(),'%'))
       )
 group by `applications`.`company_id`, `tbl_provider`.`provider_name`
 order by `Work Load` desc
```

I've added `tbl_provider.provider_name` as the second item in the `SELECT` list, added the `LEFT JOIN` to `tbl_provider`, and added `tbl_provider.provider_name` as the second item in the `GROUP BY` as well.

NOTE: code untested, typos possible.

Comment: No typos at all, it worked the way intended, thank you very much sir !

Comment: Question sir, if I wanted to replace the column "Firm % " source, getting it from a new table, I mean from this one :
CREATE TABLE `company_percentage` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `provider_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `percentage` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `company_id` (`company_id`),
  KEY `provider_id` (`provider_id`)
) ;

so instead of getting Firm % from companies.percentage I want to get it according to provider from table above,What can I do ?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN ``company_percentage`` ON (``companies``.``id`` = ``company_percentage``.``company_id`` AND ``tbl_provider``.``id`` = ``company_percentage``.``provider_id``)` - then, replace the reference to `companies`.`percentage` with `company_percentage`.`percentage` where needed. Note - this does assume that there will be one entry in `company_percentage` for each company and provider - if there's no entries, you'll get back `NULL`, and if there's multiple entries, one will be used at random (or you'll have to add the percentage to the group by, and you'll get multiple rows)

Comment: I am really grateful, thank you sir, thank you very much !